# open a certain directory and write to it in c

Tags: c, linux, file

I'm trying to implement this linux command sequence in c : 
cd /folder/folder;
echo 1000 > file;

i tried this code and it works fine :

```
int fd, len;
char buf[MAX_BUF];
fd = open("/folder/folder" "/file", O_WRONLY);
len = snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%d", 1000);
write(fd, buf, len);
```

but i want to declare : `char * a = some other folder`, If my folder would change ; and use it :

```
open(a "/file", O_WRONLY);
```

but then i get error : expected ')' before string

any ideas how to fix it or implement in different way ? Thank you.

Comment: `a "/file"` would not be valid C. Concat!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only use adjacency to concatenate string literals, not runtime strings.

To do the latter, just use `snprintf()` which you already seem to know about!

Something like:

```
char fn[1024];
const char *a = "/hello/filesystem";

snprintf(fn, sizeof fn, "%s/file", a);
```

Or, naturally, put the entire valid path in the variable to begin with:

```
const char *a = "/hello/filesystem/file";
```

but that's pretty obvious so I assumed you wanted a runtime solution.

Also, you're not "opening a certain directory", you're opening a *file* that's *in* a certain directory.

Finally, check that `open()` succeeds before relying on the file descriptor to be valid.

Comment: Thank you it worked :D , although i already tried that before writing to stackoverflow and it failed , because i declared bad route....., oh well

Answer (score 3):

You have to  use like this.

```
char a[]="path to file";
```

And in open function,

```
 open(a,O_WRONLY);
```